# MFMessageComposeViewController sms sent delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, messageui

I implemented in my app **MFMessageComposeViewController** for send sms. It works well, but I do not know if it is possible to know when the message is actually sent.

```
-(void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients {

    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

      controller.body = bodyOfMessage;    
      controller.recipients = recipients;
      controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
      [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    }
}

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result {

  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled) {

    NSLog(@"Message cancelled");

  } else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent) {

    NSLog(@"Message sent");
  }

}
```

**if (result == MessageComposeResultSent)** corresponds only to the button "send" but not really a warning if the message has been sent. Do you know if there is some way to delegate or know if the SMS was sent or not?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a result `MessageComposeResultFailed` now; not sure if it checks that or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, as of iOS 5.0, it is not possible to retrieve a successful send of a message or a successful delivery. This is the same for `MFMailComposeViewController`.

As you see the [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is rather sparse.